# Blob-Blob ADF Copy Activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have, what I assume to be a very basic question, that I cannot find an answer for.

I would like to move files from blob1 to blob2 (external to archival). I have an orchestration pipeline that would run this pipeline to basically "truncate" blob1 (copy from external blob to archival blob and then delete from external blob).

I've created linked services and datasets for both blobs and two parameters (input and output) and added two test csv files. My first step is working within the Copy Activity under the source tab:
[image]

Below I believe I am requesting to copy data in the "input_container_name"/anything/anything and to place it in:
[image]

When I run this, it completes the task, but no files are being moved, throughput is 0.

Is this the best way to tackle this task? Or should I try to get a list of all blobs in the container and then copy each blob in a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the same operation with you but I get the error when I debug the pipeline:
[image]

If we don't set the container name from parameter then the pipeline works well.

For example, I move the blob (folder and csv files) from container `test` to `test2`:
[image]

Sink dataset:

[image]

Sink:

[image]

This will help you move all the folder and csv files to another container.